# apt-get package not found for local repository

Tags: apt

I setup a local repository for a few packages. Here is the directory structure of the repository:

```
dists
dists/precise
dists/precise/main
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/python-openvswitch_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-switch_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-datapath-dkms_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Release
dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/openvswitch-common_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
```

the /etc/apt/sources.list has the following entry:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu  precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://repo1 precise main
```

sudo apt-get update

```
Ign http://repo1 precise Release.gpg
Ign http://repo1 precise Release
Ign http://repo1 precise/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://repo1 precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://repo1 precise/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://repo1 precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://repo1 precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com precise-updates/cloud-tools/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Try apt-get install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-openvswitch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-openvswitch
```

Any tips on debugging the above problem?

Solution:
I ended up creating a trivial repository structure to get it working:

This is the new structure:

```
dists
dists/python-openvswitch_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/Packages.bz2
dists/Packages
dists/Packages.gz
dists/openvswitch-switch_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
dists/openvswitch-datapath-dkms_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/openvswitch-common_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
```

The /etc/apt/sources.list has the following entry:

```
deb http://repo1/dists /
```

Now I am able to do apt-get update followed by apt-get install openvswitch-common

Comment: That's an incorrectly-structured apt repo. Binary deb files should be in a `pool` folder. See [the Ubuntu archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) for the proper structure. How did you set up your repo?

Comment: Also, you can use `file://path/to/repo` instead so that `apt` knows it's a local repo.

Comment: I created the Packages.gz file with the following command: dpkg-scanpackages binary /dev/null | gzip -9c > binary-amd64/Packages.gz. I am also doing apt-get from a different machine so file:// won't work. Still not sure how to setup pool. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: I use `reprepro` to set up a local repo using [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286). It's written for Debian, but it can easily be used for Ubuntu. Note that (if you use this method) for `Architectures`, do **not** include `all`.

Comment: I ended up trying with trivial repository setup and it seems to be working now. I created a folder under the webroot and put both deb files and Packages file under that directory. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I ended up creating a trivial repository structure to get it working:

This is the new structure:

```
dists
dists/python-openvswitch_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/Packages.bz2
dists/Packages
dists/Packages.gz
dists/openvswitch-switch_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
dists/openvswitch-datapath-dkms_2.1.2-51_all.deb
dists/openvswitch-common_2.1.2-51_amd64.deb
```

The /etc/apt/sources.list has the following entry:

```
deb http://repo1/dists /
```

Now I am able to do `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install openvswitch-common`